# Scroll Box for Display HTML content

Tags: html, css

So I have a situation where I want to put a very long Terms of Use document onto a page on my company's web site, but it was way too long to put in the main "content" area. I would like to use a scroll area, so that user can see the terms of use as rendered originally. So you can see what I mean, I need the entire section c off of the Apple web page:

http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html#APPS

I looked into putting the HTML code for that section of the Terms of Use in `<textarea>` element, but apparently `<textarea>` will not render HTML code. Is there a solution so that I do not have a web page like 4000px high? Thanks.

Comment: A Javascript pop-up window, maybe? `window.open ("terms_of_use.html","Terms of Use",menubar=0,resizable=0);`

Comment: @paulsm4 A cool way to do it, but I preferred Mike's idea which avoids Javascript. Thanks though!

Comment: Actually, I prefer Mike's idea too ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the content into a div with a fixed height, and set the css overflow property to 'auto' this will create a scrollable div

```
<div style='height:80px; overflow:auto;'>
content here
</div>
```

of course you should use a separate style sheet but that's a different story

Answer (score 2):

You can create a div to contain the content and specify a height, then user overflow: auto in your CSS to make it scrollable.

Like this:-

http://jsbin.com/ifolaf/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

You could create another .html file and have an `<iframe>` of it embedded with a set height and width.